# make with Cygwin

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to set VTK on windows (did I say it was complicated?^^).
I have successfully configured VTK with CMake and I am now trying to run make through cygwin. However when I go to the build directory and enter make all the terminal prints and does is:

> make
>
> Microsoft Windows [version 6.3.9600]
>
> (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

EDIT: when typing cygcheck
I get:

```
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
make                 4.0-2           OK
```

EDIT 2: Here is a screenshot of what I get (sorry it's in french)
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help you can give :)

EDIT 3: New screenshot + Makefile Content

[image]

Makefile content:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "MinGW Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.2

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:

    #=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

    #=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

SHELL = cmd.exe

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"

# The command to remove a file.
RM = "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = C:\Users\Lonni\VTK\VTK-6.2.0

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = C:\Users\Lonni\VTK\Build1

    #=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running         CMake cache editor..."
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake-gui.exe" -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -    B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running     CMake to regenerate build system..."
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -    B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start     C:\Users\Lonni\VTK\Build1\CMakeFiles     C:\Users\Lonni\VTK\Build1\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start     C:\Users\Lonni\VTK\Build1\CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-    build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named vtk-android

# Build rule for target.
vtk-android: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 vtk-android
.PHONY : vtk-android

# fast build rule for target.
vtk-android/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\vtk-android.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/vtk-    android.dir/build
.PHONY : vtk-android/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named vtk-compile-tools

# Build rule for target.
vtk-compile-tools: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 vtk-compile-tools
.PHONY : vtk-compile-tools

# fast build rule for target.
vtk-compile-tools/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\vtk-compile-tools.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/vtk-    compile-tools.dir/build
.PHONY : vtk-compile-tools/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:
    @echo ... all (the default if no target is provided)
    @echo ... clean
    @echo ... depend
    @echo ... vtk-android
    @echo ... edit_cache
    @echo ... rebuild_cache
    @echo ... vtk-compile-tools
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-    build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default installation of Cygwin is [quite minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21233990/142454). It doesn't include GNU `make`, so you're getting Microsoft's `make`.

You need to re-run Cygwin's `setup-*.exe` and add `make`. Chances are, you probably need other things, too. I suggest opening the Devel category and giving the contents a scan while you're in there.

---

**EDIT**, after screenshots were added to the question:

Your screenshots show several confusions. I'll go through them one by one, quoting the text in each case:

**Pas de cible spécifiée et aucun makefile n'a été trouvé**

In English, that is "No targets specified and no makefile found." This tells you that GNU make is installed and running, but that you don't have a file called `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, or `Makefile` in the current directory. It searches for those three, in order.

This is not surprising since `ls` shows that you are running it in an empty directory.

**/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/make**

There are two problems here:

1. As I said in the comments, only programs linked to `cygwin1.dll` can make sense of `/cygdrive`. Windows' `cmd.exe` has no idea what `/cygdrive` means. `c:\MinGW\bin\make` is the correct form under `cmd.exe`.
2. MinGW is not Cygwin. Any problems you have with MinGW are an entirely separate question, not related to the problems you're having with Cygwin's GNU make package.

**/usr/bin/make**

This is similar to the previous item: `cmd.exe` has no idea what to do with a POSIX path. Because Windows' file path parsing code *sometimes* treats forward slashes the same as backslashes, this gets interpreted as `c:\usr\bin\make` in this case, but there is almost certainly no `c:\usr` directory at all.

The reason this path works in the left screenshot is that Cygwin mounts your Cygwin installation directory (e.g. `c:\cygwin` or `c:\cygwin64`, by default) as the POSIX root, so that `c:\cygwin\usr` appears as `/usr` to any program linked to `cygwin1.dll` which uses POSIX APIs such as [`open(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open). This includes Cygwin's version of GNU `bash`, as you show.

You should not require the explicit path within the Cygwin Terminal window, since `/usr/bin` should be ahead of anything else in the `PATH`. If that is not the case, you might not be using the Cygwin icon that `setup.exe` created, in which case you don't have a proper login shell. Either use that icon, or mimic what it does by calling `mintty -`, not just plain `mintty`.

Comment: Correct me I am wrong, but my previous installation of cygwin had no make and I got the "command not found" error. So is that really the reason why?

Comment: @LonniBesançon: I'm assuming you have Visual Studio installed, which is how you got Microsoft `make`.

Comment: Indeed I do, but I had it installed when I tried before and I don't get the same error. How could I possibly fix the absence of make then? Because I'm pretty sure I checked it under Dev

Comment: If you're using Cygwin through the Cygwin Terminal icon installed by `setup.exe` (as opposed to the Windows console) then Cygwin programs should be first in the `PATH`, ahead of things like Visual Studio. Are you sure `ls /usr/bin/make` shows that it is installed? How about `cygcheck make` or `cygcheck -c make`?

Comment: So does giving an explicit path (`/usr/bin/make`) do the right thing?

Comment: It actually works when I'm just launching cygwin but when i'm trying to launch it from within /cygdrive/c it doesn't and tells me that the command doesn't exist

Comment: Define "it". *What* is telling you these things? Is it make, or cmd.exe, or bash, or Windows, or...? How is "within Cygwin" distinct from /cygdrive, in your mind? /cygdrive *only* makes sense to Cygwin, not to Windows.

Comment: Sorry for answering this late. I don't have access to the PC machine now (on a mac currently). Basically, I had two different windows. One which was the classic cygwin prompt. On the other one I started and typed in /cygdrive/c. When I enter cygcheck /usr/bin/make on the first one it works. When I try on the second one I get "the command doesn't exist" error. I am quite confused as I can't see any difference. Then again I'm not an expert so I don't know what could trigger such a difference...

Comment: Open a Cygwin shell (`bash`) rather than a Windows command prompt (`cmd`). On the latter, Cygwin's `make` probably isn't in the `%PATH%`.

Comment: Ok i'm gonna add what I get and edit my post because I'm still not through with it

Comment: Cannot add a picture... Not enough reputation yet. Anyway I tried what reinierpost suggested and I'm still having the same error. I have two windows. On the first one it's just cygwin that I launch, on the second cygwin and i get to my directory cd cygdrive/c/... When trying /usr/bin/make on the first one: no target. On the second one: cannot find the command

Comment: Thanks for helping me out to clarify things a little bit. I am less confused now and make works just fine :). Now still have to try and succeed in the process of making VTK ^^'.

Comment: I still have issues. I edited my post to show what I get now. Sorry i'm quite new to this

Comment: @LonniBesançon: This is turning into a "how do I use Cygwin and GNU make" tutorial. Please post the new thing as a separate question. The answer has nothing to do with anything we've already discussed.

Comment: I do feel it is quite related. I admit I was a bit confused by Cygwin in the first place but still there is something not normal here no ? I mean I can't see no reason why it would switch from the gnu make to the VS make in the use case I showed in my last screenshot. I don't mind posting an other question at all, it's just that I think it's still quite related

Comment: @LonniBesançon: Why don't you believe me when I tell you that the answer to this latest question is different and unrelated to the previous discussion? If you knew enough to second-guess me, you would know the correct command already.

Comment: Alright ok ! Didn't mean to upset you at all. Was just skeptical about it all in the first place that's all. I will create then an other question with the screenshot and make file

Comment: Done :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514661/visual-studio-make-instead-of-gnu-make-with-cygwin Sorry again if I offended you