# Cygwin error: "child_info_fork::abort: Loaded to different address:"

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin

I am trying to build my software using cygwin-x86(32 bit version) on Windows-7. 

Cygwin-x64(64 bit) works perfectly fine on the same machine. I want to build 32-bit executable.

Whenever I try cygwin-x86, I get the following errors:

> [main] make 7780 child_info_fork::abort:
>   C:\cygwin\bin\cygiconv-2.dll: Loaded to different address:
>   parent(0x440000) != child(0x5F0000) 
> **make:** **fork: Resource temporarily**
>   **unavailable**

I have checked this thread [Cygwin Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300722/cygwin-error-bash-fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable)

I have already tried everything mentioned in there, but I still continue to face the same issue. 

Whenever i try **/usr/bin/rebaseall -v** or **cd /usr/bin && ./rebaseall -v** as mentioned in the step 7 of the accepted answer in the above mentioned thread, I get this error:

> /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/bin/cygvtv_stubs-0.dll: skipped
>   because wrong  machine type.
>   /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/bin/cygz.dll: skipped because wrong
>   machine type. 
> **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

I get this wrong machine type error for a lot of other .dll's as well.

As mentioned earlier I have cygwin-64 installed on my machine & working as expected. But while running **rebaseall** it is somehow looking for **x86-64-pc-cygwin** instead of 32 bit version.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The thread is obsolete.

run `/usr/bin/rebase-trigger`, close all cygwin processes and run again `setup-x86.exe`. Also without installing anything will execute a rebase for you.

You can also specify the option full.

Additional note:
The most likely cause of fork problems on 32 bit system are too many programs and libraries installed.

for example:
`/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/bin/cygz.dll`

belongs to `cygwin64-zlib` a cross library for building cygwin64 programs from cygwin32. Do you really need it ? If not, as I suspect, remove all cywgin64 packages .

Comment: Strangely enough, the problem was solved (i.e. I could do _svn up_) while setup was running, but once setup ended it was broken again. I solved this by canceling setup once _svn up_ was functional. So far without side effects.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft  `Rebaseall` method was replaced by `rebase-trigger` https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-02/msg00005.html

Answer (score 7):

The problem can also be triggered by an anti-virus program.  (I saw it happening with Avast.)  You can test if this is the cause by disabling it.

Comment: it was my case indeed. Using AVG!

Comment: AVG blocked me too. You can click in the tray, right-click AVG, and turn "protection is on" into the off position. I then went back to git shell and typed "eval $(ssh-agent -s)" and success. The I reenabled my AVG.

Comment: thank you ! I just installed AVG and it was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Could also be caused by this update
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4561616/windows-10-update-kb4561616

Comment: Yep, for me it was KB4566516.  I back it off, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also kill each of the latest process of ash, dash or bash that was forked, setup.exe will simply skip this script and continue with the rest.
I had to kill about 10-20 of them, mostly in latex postinstall scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to remove the `.new` file extention of the libs from c:\cygwin64\bin\

I had the same problem using git. various dlls depending on the git command used where included in the error message stating that it was loaded to "different adress".

In fact a corporate antivirus or a loaded program had probably prevent un update during the rebase phase while installing a new program (git-svn in my case)
some required libraries where not installed but cleverly left in the target with the `.new` file extention.

I just had to remove the `.new` extention (and rename the original lib to `.old`) to solve the problem.

In my case the list of lib involved was:

```
cygcrypto-1.1.dll
cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
cygintl-8.dll
cygwin1.dll
```