# hadoop-2.7.5 hbase1.2.6 spark flume cygwin

Tags: apache-spark, cygwin, bigdata, flume

While starting hbase I'm getting the following error.

```
sh start-hbase.sh
: Name or service not knownstname 127.0.0.1
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../logs/hbase-manou-master-asus.out
starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../logs/hbase-manou-1-regionserver-asus.out
      1 [main] bash 6772 fork: child -1 - forked process 8656 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/usr/local/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase-config.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

What do I need to look at for this issue?

I'm using windows and cygwin for installation

Comment: 1) See if you have any cygwin package issues via `cygcheck -c` 2) Look for multiple versions of `cygwin1.dll` on your system and delete all but the most recent.  3) Run `/bin/rebaseall` from within `ash` or `dash`.

Comment: /usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/bin/cygz.dll: skipped because wrong machine typ
e.

Comment: Please help ; look at this error

Comment: did you look up the error and try to fix?  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602608/cygwin-error-child-info-forkabort-loaded-to-different-address/37616907) is just one suggestion I found when googling that specific error.  If the suggestions there don't work, I bet you can figure out how to search for more.

Comment: have you tried starting hbase since that cygz.dll warning?  It may not be relevant.