# ndkbuild Command Is not recognised

Tags: android, bash, android-ndk, cygwin

I am new to NDK and cygwin. and after installing NDK, I used cygwin to run the following command:

```
§ ndk-build
```

but the result was:

```
-bash: ndk-build: command not found
```

The below image is to show how I set the path for NDK, is it correct?

How to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the NDK_ATH variable to `C:\NDK\android-ndk-r10d`. It could not include the ndk-build command

Comment: ok, nowwhen i type $ndk-build in cygwin, i receive "command not found"

Comment: Your ndk-build will be in your ndk bin directory..Please set it to bin directory

Comment: i checked the bin directory it was inside this directory "prebuilt\windows-x86_64\" but it has no ndk-buil file

Comment: set the path to C:\NDK\android-ndk-r10d and restart the command prompt..and check

Comment: know i receive, "cant find 'make' program, please install cygwin make package or define GNUMAKE variable to point to it"...i search fro some related post, and i found one here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661939/where-can-i-download-an-offline-installer-of-cygwin      and i downloaded the make package required and installed it offline, but i still receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

Being able to execute `ndk-build` does not depend on setting the environmental variable `NDK_PATH` or `NDK_HOME` to the correct location. No!

Execution of this command depends on your `PATH` variable (might be `Path` on windows). So what you need to do is to edit your path variable on windows and add the location of the `android-ndk` to that path and you are set to use the `ndk-build` command.

To get access to the `path` variable it is the same process to get to the window you have open above. But this time, you look under `System variables` and find `Path`.

- Copy the contents of the path variable to a text editor (preferably one that wraps long lines)
- navigate to the android ndk folder (make sure you are inside it)
- copy it's location from the navigation bar of your file explorer
- now go back to your text editor with the path variable content in it and add a **semicolon [;]** to the end of the path
- finally paste the location you copied to end of that path (after the semicolon)
- Now copy everything from your text editor and replace the value of your path variable with what you have copied
- Ok -> Ok -> Confirm -> Save -> etc...

Close and reopen your command line and try typing `ndk-build`.

Any troubles, leave a comment